# Adding Unit Test for Exceptions and Error handling to Service

Tags: java, unit-testing

For example when you try to use one of the methods update or delete methods and pass null parameters , if we have a method that saves or updates a database example is my update Shopping Cart method below

```
 public ShoppingCart updateShoppingCart(ShoppingCart shoppingCart) throws AccessDeniedException
    {
        BigDecimal cartTotal = new BigDecimal(0);

        List<CartItem> cartItemList = cartItemRepository.findByShoppingCart(shoppingCart);

        for (CartItem cartItem : cartItemList) {
            if (cartItem.getBook().getInStockNumber() > 0) {
                cartTotal = cartTotal.add(cartItem.getSubTotal());
            }
        } 
        shoppingCart.setGrandTotal(cartTotal);
        shoppingCartRepository.save(shoppingCart);
        return shoppingCart;
    }
```

if for example we cant save because the parameter for this method is null or some other error or exceptions ,how can we add a unit test that checks for this ?

currently my unit test is this , how to go about the error and exception tests?

```
@Test
    public void updateShoppingCartTest() throws Exception {

        ShoppingCart shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();
// objects instance here
        List<CartItem> cartItemList = Arrays.asList(cartItem1, cartItem2);

        when(cartItemRepository.findByShoppingCart(shoppingCart)).thenReturn(cartItemList);

        for (CartItem cartItem : cartItemList) {

            if (cartItem.getBook().getInStockNumber() > 0) {
                cartTotal = cartTotal.add(cartItem.getSubTotal());
            }
        }

        shoppingCart.setGrandTotal(cartTotal);
        when(shoppingCartRepository.save(shoppingCart)).thenReturn(shoppingCart);

        ShoppingCart cart = shoppingCartService.updateShoppingCart(shoppingCart);

        Assert.assertNotNull(cart);
        Mockito.verify(cartItemRepository).findByShoppingCart(shoppingCart);
        Mockito.verify(shoppingCartRepository).save(shoppingCart);
    }
```

Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have different approaches, I like to use `ExpectedException` rule that allows me to show what exception I am expecting and the message withing that rule.

Here you can find more info

https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/exception-testing#expectedexception-rule